# Python subprocess communicate hangs

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I know that this is a frequently asked question and I've tried any solution approach which I could find here and on other sites^but couldn't solve my problem.
My dilemma looks as follows (on Windows):

I have a main script (main.py) where I am creating a subprocess via Popen calling another script (sniffer.py) . Afterwards I am doing some stuff in main.py and finally want to send a character to the subprocess to finish the endless loop in sniffer.py and finally the whole subprocess.

main.py

```
process = Popen(["python", "sniffer.py", receiverIP, senderIP, "udp", path],stdin=PIPE)
#do some stuff
process.communicate('terminate')
```

sniffer.py

```
def check(done):
    while True:
        if sys.stdin.read() == 'terminate':
            done = True
            break
def sniff(someparams):
    done = False
    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=check, args=(done,))
    input_thread.daemon = True
    input_thread.start()
    while True:
        #do some stuff
        if done:
            break
```

I've also tried to combine the communicate call with a stdin.write, but it had no effect.

Note: I've noticed that, the while loop in sniffer.py doesn't continue after my communicate() call (the whole script just hangs)

Comment: Could you specify how specifically it 'didn't work'? Please provide your output to aid in debugging.

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with `subprocess`.

You change `done` to `True` locally. You have to define it globally for the last loop to exit properly.

```
done = False

def check():
    global done
    while True:
        if sys.stdin.read() == 'terminate':
            done = True
            break
def sniff(someparams):
    global done
    done = False
    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=check)
    input_thread.daemon = True
    input_thread.start()
    while True:
        #do some stuff
        if done:
            break
```

Comment: It didn't help, the code still hangs on communicate(). The communicate call correctly sets done to true but the while loop in sniff() hangs after that

Comment: try to add a print statement in your `while True` loop, and after it too to see if it's reached.